# Does it make sense to make the copy constructor explicit in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, keyword, copy-constructor

I know that the keyword `explicit` is used to prevent implict conversions of a passed argument to match the parameter list. I learned that one should always write the `explicit` keyword in a constructor with only one argument but does that apply to the copy constructor too? Am I introducing any problems to my code if I write it that way?

Comment: Sure Class f() { return Class(); } - explicit is bad here

Comment: `Foo copy_foo = foo;` will also fail

Comment: "I learned that one should always write the explicit keyword in a constructor with only one argument" -- You learned wrong. You only need to do that when you want to prevent the constructor from being used implicitly. That's why the keyword is called `explicit`.

Comment: @hvd the rule comes from a desire to prevent accidental type conversions. If you don't prefer to make constructors explicit it can lead to surprising bugs.

Comment: As I already said, I am aware of what the explicit does. The question should possibly better be: Are there any downsides of makeing the copy constructor explicit. Does it give me a hard time writing operator += in a string class or anything like that? @vsoftco I already stumbled about this and that's not what I was asking.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, that matches what I said. Type conversions are implicit uses of the constructor. If you don't want the constructor to be used implicitly, make it `explicit`. If you do want a constructor to be used implicitly, don't make it `explicit`. A hard rule to always make all constructors `explicit` that have one argument, without thinking about whether `explicit` makes sense for that constructor, makes no sense as a rule.

Comment: @fridolin69 The answer in that question shows downsides of making the copy constructor explicit, in similar spirit as earlier comments on this question: what would otherwise be perfectly normal usage is suddenly prohibited.